# Sharing Dictionary Values

Tags: c#, dictionary

Full disclosure: I'm new to C# and not generally a procedural programmer - I'm a SQL Server developer primarily. This may mean that my question is either naive or simple. Apologies if this is the case.

I've created a data processing class with a number of methods. These methods all use elements of the same set of metadata to drive the processing. The metadata is obtained from a single line of data returned from a SQL Server metadata store.

Initially, I converted this data line to variables and passed these around the methods explicitly. Which got messy quickly. So I then moved to a Fields based approach, which made things tidier, but needs management if the metadata structure changes.

To try to make things more adaptable, I then implemented a Dictionary based approach, using a SQLDataReader and a loop to convert the column names and values to key / value pairs. The bit I'm struggling with is referencing this dictionary. Can I avoid having to explicitly pass the dictionary object to each method as I am now, e.g.

```
public void Main()
{
    // create a dictionary and add values
    Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"cat", "miaow"},
        {"dog", "woof"},
        {"iguana", "grekkkk?"}
    };

    // get a value from the dictionary and display it
    MessageBox.Show(myDictionary["cat"]);

    // call another procedure
    up(myDictionary);

    // call another procedure that calls another procedure
    sh(myDictionary);
}

public void up(Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary) 
{
    // get a value from the dictionary and display it
    MessageBox.Show(myDictionary["dog"]);
}

public void sh(Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary)
{
    // call another procedure
    up(myDictionary);
}
```

Or am I barking up the wrong tree completely?

I've seen this post:[sharing dictionary contents between class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057960/sharing-dictionary-contents-between-class-instances), but attempting to understand how to use this is well beyond my current knowledge level.

Edit: Here's how I've done it, based on the answers from Jon and Rodrigo:

```
// create an empty dictionary 
    Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
        };

    public void Main()
    {
        // build the dictionary
        BuildDictionary();

        // get a value from the dictionary and display it
        MessageBox.Show(myDictionary["cat"]);

        // call another procedure
        up();

        // call another procedure that calls another procedure
        sh();

    }

    public void BuildDictionary()
    {

        // note that in implementation this uses a dynamic process
        // rather than just explicitly setting values
        myDictionary.Add("cat", "miaow");
        myDictionary.Add("dog", "woof");
        myDictionary.Add("iguana", "grekkk?");
    }

    public void up() 
    {

        // get a value from the dictionary and display it
        MessageBox.Show(myDictionary["dog"]);

    }

    public void sh()
    {

        // call another procedure
        up();

    }
```

Much tidier. Thanks to both.

Iain

Comment: Is the dictionary naturally a part of the state of your class? If so, you should probably make it a field. (I'd also strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, and give your methods more meaningful names than `sh` and `up`, if those are really representative...) If fields are *also* beyond your current knowledge level, I'd advise reading a good introductory book on C# - Stack Overflow is great for specific questions, but not for learning core language principles.

Comment: I would +1 this but can't see an option to? Perhaps my noob status is the reason. Just to answer your point on names, I have sensible and descriptive names in my script, these were just for illustration. I also plan to invest in a good book. Finding the time to read it will be the challenge, as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your very specific case, where you are just using the member inside your own class, you should just set dictionary as a private member of your class (private is the default behavior for members, its implicit).

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"cat", "miaow"},
            {"dog", "woof"},
            {"iguana", "grekkkk?"}

        };
public void Main()
{

    // create a dictionary and add values


    // get a value from the dictionary and display it
    MessageBox.Show(myDictionary["cat"]);

    // call another procedure
    up();

    // call another procedure that calls another procedure
    sh();

}

public void up() 
{

    // get a value from the dictionary and display it
    MessageBox.Show(myDictionary["dog"]);

}

public void sh()
{

    // call another procedure
    up();

}
```

You should also take a look at modifiers. For more info Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tcf2h8w.aspx)